# Find a point on the screen

Tags: java, coordinates

There seems to be many questions similar to this but none that I could find that directly answer the question.

Basically, I have 2 rectangles inside a frame. (My frame, my "screen", and my "level") when making a game. I know the Screen width and height as well as the level's width and height.

When I click on the screen and getX() for where I click, it returns the point on the screen which (since the coord's on the screen do not change no matter where I'm looking, I.E. (0,0) is the the upper left of the screen and (screen.width,screen.height) is in the bottom right) is a problem because the objects on the screen need to move across the Level.

I was wondering if there was an easy way to get the point on the level with the information. As an example:

Screen -
           Width = 10, Height = 5.
           Clicked = (5,2)
Level-
           Width = 20, Hieght = 10
           Clicked = (?,?)

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully understand what you mean by this:

> Screen - Width = 10, Height = 5. Clicked = (5,2) Level- Width = 20, Hieght = 10 Clicked = (?,?)

But if you simply want to get the point on the 'level' rectangle where they clicked relative to the rectangle (i.e. (0,0) would be the top left of the retangle) then you can have the 'level' rectangle component implement a [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) like so

```
component.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         int x = e.getX();
         int y = e.getY();
         System.out.println(x+","+y);//these co-ords are relative to the component
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry the formatting of that was bad... I meant to say that the Screen's width is 10 and height is 5 and the spot where you click on the screen is (5,2) where as the Level's width is 20and height is 10 and I need to know the point clicked on the screen relative to the level to compare (5,2) with.
Also, I cant put a MouseListener on the level for a few different reasons. Just the way I have my implementation set, the mouselistener will only be on the screen.

Comment: Is your 'screen' essentially a view of the 'level'? Does your screen essentially stay still and the level moves? or do both stay still? Regardless you will need to know the position of your 'level' relative to your 'screen' before you can work out the point clicked on the level